# Why does the MSIX not automatically check for updates every time the application runs when sideloading is enabled?

Tags: wpf, azure, visual-studio, .net-5, msix

**Question:**

Why does the MSIX not automatically check for updates every time the application runs when sideloading is enabled?

**Context:**

We are migrating a WPF application to Azure and have created an MSIX installer with sideloading enabled and set to check for updates every time the application launches. Accordingly, the `*.appinstaller` file is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<AppInstaller
    Uri="https://<AppService>.azurewebsites.net/<AppName>.Setup.appinstaller"
    Version="1.0.1.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller/2017/2">
    <MainBundle
        Name="<SomeGuid>"
        Version="1.0.1.0"
        Publisher="CN=<CertificateName>"
        Uri="https://<AppService>.azurewebsites.net/<AppName>.Setup_1.0.1.0_Development_Test/<AppName>.Setup_1.0.1.0_x64_Development.msixbundle" />
    <UpdateSettings>
        <OnLaunch
            HoursBetweenUpdateChecks="0" />
    </UpdateSettings>
</AppInstaller>
```

Unfortunately, every time we publish an update to the package to Azure, the application does not `automatically` check for any updates, and so it does not prompt us to update. However, when we go to the application's published weblink and click to install, the installer will see that the application is already installed and that an update is available.

**Troubleshooting:**

We tried adding to the app manifest's Content URI (tab) to the `*.appinstaller` site, but that did not work. I noticed that the `*.appinstaller` is appending the text `_Test` to the path name. I am not sure why that is being added. I have tried recreating the installer package in order to rule out any potential configuration errors. Could that be the source of the problem?

I have also enabled `Use developer feature` and followed all other instructions provided by Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/application-management/sideload-apps-in-windows-10

Note: we tried creating a `ClickOnce` publish profile and that works. It does not make sense why sideloading works for `ClickOnce` but not `MSIX`.

Comment: Are you sure it doesn't do a silent update the first you start the app after there is an update? Did you try to start it a second time?

Comment: @mm8 No, it does not appear to be doing a silent update as the version stays the same. I get the version, both before and after running it multiple times, by right clicking the icon in the start menu and going into `App Settings`. I tried both rebooting and deploying a different application that is a WinForms appliciation. The current application in this question is WPF.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what I see [here](http://thewindowsupdate.com/2019/02/22/handling-application-updates-with-app-installer-and-msix-in-windows-10-19h1/) you need to update the schema to 2018:

```
 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/appinstaller/2018"
```

Also, what version of Windows 10 are you running? I see the [appinstaller update settings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/msix/app-installer/update-settings) have been introduced gradually, older versions of Win 10 do no support all of them.

Another older issue from 2019 seems to highlight a [limitation for apps launched via a desktop or taskbar shortcut.](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/published-msixappx-does-not-check-for-updates-when/776276)

Comment: That worked. Thank you. I am running Windows 20H2, OS Build 19042.928. I am posting a new question because the `appinstallers` settings seem to be statically set by the template itself. In other words, the correct settings keep getting overwritten every time I build a new version.

Comment: Follow-up question here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/67285329/4630376